# Active a method within a function

Tags: python

Is there a way that when you make a function, give it 2 parameters the name of the object and method. And in the body you apply the the method as you would do outside of the function, for example: Boat2.Damage.

EXAMPLE:

```
class boat:
    def __init__(self,):
        self.hp = 100
    def damage(self):
        self.hp = self.hp - 50

def use_card(name,attribute):
    return name.attribute

use_card(boat2, damage())
```

Is there anyway to make this work?

Comment: `getattr(Boat2, 'Damage')()`? Please give a [mcve], not a picture.

Comment: Firstly, instead of screenshot please add code to the question. Secondly, your function is just making it `class.function`; why to pass class `class` & `function` separately?

Comment: Sorry, i will post the code. Why i pass it seperately? Because i create a game, and i want that the name of the enemy comes in name, and then a method to have it do something with the given enemy.

Comment: Then a more straightforward issue might be a dictionary mapping enemy name to enemy instance, on which you can call methods directly.

Comment: Dictionary mapping? You mean the dictionary with a key and a value? Well, i have around 28 methods and 4 enemy's. that would mean 100 mapping.

Comment: Maybe you should show a bit more of your code then to show what you are actually trying to do. Usually, a proper mapping will help you *reduce* the amount of code you need to write.

Comment: Yes, dictionaries have keys and values. No, I don't mean mapping each method of each enemy separately. Just map the name of the enemy to the instance, then you only need four entries in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but the following shows how you could call a method (from within function) by supplying an argument containing its name as a string:

```
class Boat:
    def __init__(self,):
        self.hp = 100
    def damage(self):
        print('damage() called')
        self.hp = self.hp - 50

def use_card(obj, attrname):
    return getattr(obj, attrname)()

boat2 = Boat()
use_card(boat2, "damage")  # -> damage() called
```

Is this what you want to do?

Comment: Good to hear. Do you understand what it does (how it works)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! This is exactly what i tried to do. When you manually enter an object and a method as parameters in the function call, that it links them together.

And for future readers, why i wanted to do this? Because i have a game with enemies and cards. I wanted to give the user the option that he can click the enemy (the name of the enemy will come on the place of the obj parameter , the card (it is a method that does something to the enemy) comes on the place of the attrname parameter. And this way, the method gets called on the object!

For example, enemy name (object) is: Tom, card name(method) is damage.
When you call the function you gave those names as parameters so:
use_card(Tom, "damage"), in the function this happens: **tom.damage**. Pretty awesome!

Comment: For `use_card(Tom, "damage")` to work, `Tom` would have to be the name of a program _variable_ containing a Python object. The same object could have also be in one named `Dick`, `foobar`, or whatever—including a single element of a list, like `enemies[3]`. I think the problem is a confusion you have between a variable's name and the contents of the object it refers to, which might be character string with the name of something which often (but may not be) related to the name given the variable. For example, the variable named `company` might be assigned to a string containing `"Google"`.